# Parse URL parameter from string

Tags: php

I have a string as follows

```
http://solo.dev/module-1/behavioural-safety/?id=7#15
```

and I want to get the id value for the above string, normally $_GET['id'], however not an option as this is being executed elsewhere.

What's the best way to get this value from the above string?

Comment: I do not know if it's the best practice. However you can first split on ? then on = to have the two vars, first the var name, second the value

Comment: Aye this was my go to, however my concern is, what if there's more than one query in the URL? @Goikiu

Comment: after the first split (on ?) you can search, if present semicolumn (;) you'll have more then one var, otherwise you got only one problably :)

Comment: You can try this
`$request_uri ="http://solo.dev/module-1/behavioural-safety/?id=7#15";
$url = explode('?', $request_uri);
$url = end($url);
$url = explode("#", $url);
print_r($url[0]);`